# get 405 error while making post API call with token header

Tags: ajax, api, post

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
           //contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            crossDomain: true,
            //xhrFields: { withCrendentials: true },
         //   beforeSend: function (req) {

              //  req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
              //  req.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
              //  req.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                //req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "ST signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
               //     req.setRequestHeader("X-Mobile","false");
           //     },
                 headers: {

                "Authorization": "ST signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",


           },

            data: source,
            timeout: 10000,
            success: function (data) {
```

on chrome console i got this error

XMLHttpRequest cannot load url:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:53208' is therefore not allowed access

on Mozilla console i got this error

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at url :xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` does not implement the [CORS protocol](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol). As long as it doesn't, you won't have access to it through XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: but how to implement CORS ? can you explain if you have any code example